# google map marker dragging doesnt work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, draggable

I cant able to get the longitude and latitude after dragging the marker please notify my mistake

thank you in advance

js code here:

```
<script>
 function initialize_map(lat,lng) {
        $("#request-form").show();
        latitude = parseFloat(lat);
        longitude = parseFloat(lng);
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 14,
          center: myLatlng
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!',
            draggable: true,
        });

         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (marker) {
          var latLng = marker.latLng;
    document.getElementById("latitude").value = latLng.lat()
    document.getElementById("longitude").value = latLng.lng();
});

      }
```

Comment: [Your code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/ntewpspv/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing marker into the dragend function handler, pass event instead.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) { 
...
}
```